# How do I structure/design a multipage dash application to avoid duplicate callback errors?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to refactor my one-page dashboard app into a multipage app in order to provide an "About" page where I lay out some details about the dashboard. However, I run into duplicate callback erorrs. Note that

1. When I first start the application the root page loads fine and works as expected.
2. If I refresh the page I get duplicate callback errors
3. If I navigate to the about page I get duplicate callback errors

I provide below a full MWE which reproduces the error.

## My thoughts

I think the issue lies with the fact that I am getting the `Dash` instance in the pages via `app = dash.get_app()`. Whenever the duplicate callback error occurs, I notice in the callback tree debugger tool that the connections have doubled.

I think I need to pass the `app` to the utility functions, since I need them to set up the callback. I decided to put the callback inside the utility function, because

1. I am generating a lot of identically looking components where the figure data and titles are different. In this way I can generate all these components by calling the same utility function by passing the relevant parameters.
2. I think the code is simple when the callback for updating the figure lives inside the function responsible for generating the figure.

## Tree structure

```
.
├── main.py
├── pages
│   ├── about.py
│   └── home.py
└── utils.py
```

## `utils.py`

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

from dash import Dash, Patch, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

def sine(xs: np.array) -> np.array:
    return 100 * np.sin(xs)

def make_figure(app: Dash) -> html.Div:
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=None,
        y=None,
        name="Randomized Data"
    ))

    fig.update_layout(height=800, template="plotly_dark")

    @app.callback(
        Output("plotly-figure", "figure"),
        Input("dcc-interval", "n_intervals")
    )
    def update(n_clicks: int) -> Patch:
        xs = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 100)
        ys = sine(xs) * np.random.random(size=len(xs))

        patch = Patch()
        patch["data"][0]["x"] = xs
        patch["data"][0]["y"] = ys

        return patch

    return html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id="plotly-figure")
    ])

def make_random_title(app: Dash) -> html.Div:
    adjectives = [
        "Affable",
        "Affluent",
        "Deprived",
        "Destitute",
        "Elaborate",
        "Evocative",
        "Frivolous",
        "Gritty",
        "Immense"
    ]

    nouns = [
        "Crackdown",
        "Culprit",
        "Discrepancy",
        "Endorsement",
        "Enmity",
        "Gravity",
        "Immunity",
        "Juncture",
        "Legislation",
        "Offspring"
    ]

    @app.callback(
        Output("random-title", "children"),
        Input("dcc-interval", "n_intervals")
    )
    def update(n_intervals: int) -> html.H1:
        return html.H1(f"{np.random.choice(adjectives)} {np.random.choice(nouns)}")
    
    return html.Div(children=[
        f"{np.random.choice(adjectives)} {np.random.choice(nouns)}"
    ], id="random-title")
```

## `pages/about.py`

```py
import dash

dash.register_page(__name__, path="/about")

from dash import html

def layout() -> html.Div:
    return html.Div(children=[
        html.H1("About Page")
    ])
```

## `pages/home.py`

```py
import dash
import utils

dash.register_page(__name__, path="/")

app = dash.get_app()

from dash import html

def layout() -> html.Div:
    return html.Div(children=[
        utils.make_random_title(app),
        utils.make_figure(app)
    ])
```

## `main.py`

```py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html, dcc

def main() -> Dash:
    app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])

    app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        dash.page_container,
        dcc.Interval(id="dcc-interval", n_intervals=0, interval=1000)
    ])

    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = main()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## `requirements.txt`

```
plotly
dash
numpy
dash-bootstrap-components
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the initial problem was that you were binding (the same) callbacks multiple times. Specifically, because you made `layout` of the home page a function instead of a variable,

```
def layout() -> html.Div:
    return html.Div(children=[
        utils.make_random_title(app),
        utils.make_figure(app)
    ])
```

this function will be executed every time the home page is loaded, thus invoking `utils.make_random_title`, which tries to bind this callback (again)

```
@app.callback(
    Output("random-title", "children"),
    Input("dcc-interval", "n_intervals")
)
def update(n_intervals: int) -> html.H1:
    return html.H1(f"{np.random.choice(adjectives)} {np.random.choice(nouns)}")
```

resulting in a duplicate callback error. The solution is to make sure that the code defining the callback(s) is only executed only *once*.

There are many ways achieve that goal, with the simplest for your case being to change the `layout` function into a `layout` variable. However, the path that you came up with (using the `@callback` decorator from within the global scope), is also perfectly valid approach. In fact, I tend to prefer this structure for readability (unless it hinders code reuse).

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize that the `layout()` function inside each page would be executed at each page reload, but I it makes sense now when you say it.

Answer (score 1):

**The root of this problem is perhaps poor code design. Or rather, code design with difficult-to-foresee consequences. I would really like if the dash community could come up with a right way to structure the code. One way that always will work without hacks, and that can be simplified for simple applications.**

To fix the duplicate callback errors you need to refactor the code so that the callbacks found in `utils.py` are moved to the relevant page file. That eliminates the need to pass down the `app` object, which I think was the root of the problem.

The following updated file contents run without errors (and also fixed the same problem within my production dashboard and not just within the MWE):

## `utils.py`

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

from dash import html, dcc

adjectives = [
    "Affable",
    "Affluent",
    "Deprived",
    "Destitute",
    "Elaborate",
    "Evocative",
    "Frivolous",
    "Gritty",
    "Immense"
]

nouns = [
    "Crackdown",
    "Culprit",
    "Discrepancy",
    "Endorsement",
    "Enmity",
    "Gravity",
    "Immunity",
    "Juncture",
    "Legislation",
    "Offspring"
]

def sine(xs: np.array) -> np.array:
    return 100 * np.sin(xs)

def make_figure() -> html.Div:
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=None,
        y=None,
        name="Randomized Data"
    ))

    fig.update_layout(height=800, template="plotly_dark")

    return html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id="plotly-figure")
    ])

def make_random_title() -> html.Div:
    return html.Div(children=[
        f"{np.random.choice(adjectives)} {np.random.choice(nouns)}"
    ], id="random-title")
```

## `pages/home.py`

```py
import dash
import utils

import numpy as np

from dash import html, Patch, callback
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

dash.register_page(__name__, path="/")

@callback(
    Output("plotly-figure", "figure"),
    Input("dcc-interval", "n_intervals")
)
def update(n_clicks: int) -> Patch:
    xs = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 100)
    ys = utils.sine(xs) * np.random.random(size=len(xs))

    patch = Patch()
    patch["data"][0]["x"] = xs
    patch["data"][0]["y"] = ys

    return patch

@callback(
    Output("random-title", "children"),
    Input("dcc-interval", "n_intervals")
)
def update(n_intervals: int) -> html.H1:
    return html.H1(f"{np.random.choice(utils.adjectives)} {np.random.choice(utils.nouns)}")

def layout() -> html.Div:
    return html.Div(children=[
        utils.make_random_title(),
        utils.make_figure()
    ])
```